# Import/VAT implications of using Google Cloud services in EU

Tags: european-union, vat, google

I am considering using [Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com) services as a competitor in a [Kaggle competition](https://www.kaggle.com/c/youtube8m). To encourage new use - and likely due to recent acquisition of Kaggle by Google - the cloud service is offering an amount of "free" credits on signup and additional credits to top up resources used exclusively for the competition. The main reason for considering Google Cloud instead of Amazon or others, is that the competition has been set up to make using Google Cloud very easy - for instance the terabyte of competition data is made available directly.

The Google Cloud/Kaggle combination in theory makes entering the competition very affordable, compared to e.g. investing £3000 in a new PC capable of processing the data locally.

However, I have come across a problem when signing up to Google Cloud. I am based in European Union (UK), and Google Cloud does not support regular consumers using the service, like for instance Google Play does. Instead users of the service must make their own tax arrangements. There is a [Google help page explaining about needing to register as a business](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6090602)

I can justify that there is an economic benefit (self training, and a very small potential of qualifying for a prize on this or future related competitions). So I am willing to declare a business relationship with Google Cloud.

However, at that point I am stuck. I believe if I sign up and use the service, that I have effectively agreed to take on all responsibilities towards dealing with the EU tax. But I have no clue where to start in order to do this correctly. I am also concerned that even using the "free" credits - up to $300 regular price - that I would need to declare receiving these and pay some kind of tax on them. Possibly import duty as well as VAT?

There is a [thread about this at Kaggle, where I have tried to ask for advice](https://www.kaggle.com/c/youtube8m/discussion/28947), but neither Google Cloud sponsors nor Kaggle will offer advice to the affected competitors.

What do I need to do, to ensure I do not transgress any tax rules or other financial requirements in order to use Google Cloud service?